# Is it possible to filter the user through roles (a JSON array) in EasyAdmin?

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony, doctrine-orm, easyadmin

I use **EasyadminBundle** for the Backend of a **Symfony** application.

I'd like to filter my users through their `$roles` with 1 table with only the `ROLE_WEBMASTER`, another on with the `ROLE_ADMIN` and the final one with the loosers (`ROLE_USER`).

Unfortunately the `$roles` member of the `User` class is an array.

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];
}
```

My storage back-end is SQLite.

I tried two solutions:

### 1. use search queries

```
- { icon: user-tie, label: admin, entity: User, params: {action: search, query: ROLE_ADMIN}}
```

> do nothing

### 2. use a DQL filter

```
webmaster:
    class: App\Entity\User
    label: Webmaster
    list:
        dql_filter: "'ROLE_WEBMASTER' IN entity.sqlRoles()"
```

with

```php
public function  sqlRoles():string
{
    return implode(', ',$this->getRoles());
}
```

but it launch the following error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("[Syntax Error] line 0, col 65: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'IN'").

---

Is there a way to perform this kind of trick or do I need to forget this idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to filter a JSON array in **EasyadminBundle**, it turns out that you don't need to use `dql_filter` as `filters` are already built in the bundle.

First you need to do some preparation in your entity description :

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        User:
            class: App\Entity\User
            list:
                filters:
                    - { property: roles, type: array }
```

as the filter is now set up on the entity we can reach it in our menu :

```
easy_admin:
    design:
        menu:
            - { icon: user-cog, label: webmaser, entity: User, params: { action: list, filters: { roles: { comparison: like, value: [ROLE_WEBMASTER] } } } }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know easyAdmin, but that DQL does not compute.

```
dql_filter: "'ROLE_WEBMASTER' IN entity.sqlRoles()"
```

You need to remember than whatever you write on DQL has to end up being translated to plain old SQL. That means that using entity methods is not going to work.

Think about it: these methods can't be used until the object is instantiated, and can't be instantiated until after is retrieved, and retrieval happens *only when the SQL statement is run*, so no `WHERE` filtering can be performed at this point.

Problem is that with vanilla Doctrine, you wont be able to filter by the contents of property of a JSON property, basically using [JSON_CONTAINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains), which Doctrine does not include support for.

However, not all hope is lost. There are extensions available that add support for these functions for different back-ends, [like this one](https://github.com/ScientaNL/DoctrineJsonFunctions).

If you install and enable it, you can change your DQL filter to:

```
dql_filter: "JSON_CONTAINS(entity.roles, '\"ROLE_WEBMASTER\"', '$')"
```

With a little bid of fiddling on your part to get everything tied together, this should work.

Sadly, since you are using SQLite, you won't be able to use the above. SQLite is great for development and embedded use, but it's not as feature rich as fully fledged RDBMS.

Comment: I'm struggling because it should work but the extension that you propose doesn't add JSON_CONTAINS to SQLlite (which is the database I'm currently using). So I'll wait a bit to see if I can find something else without changing database.

Comment: Problem is no the extension I propose, but that SQLite does not have JSON support out of the box, and even if you enable platform support differs greatly (e.g., this function). It's likely you do not even have the extension enabled. You should mention these things in your question, so answers address the issue more directly :)

Comment: I've learn a lot of things about JSON and database but the initial question is more about easy-admin than DQL, and it turns out that there is a solution that work both with SQLlite and mySQL

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution which worked for me by using `dql_filter`, hope it helps:

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        Player:
          class: App\Entity\User
          list:
            dql_filter: "entity.roles LIKE '%%ROLE_PLAYER%%'"
        Admin:
          class: App\Entity\User
          list:
            dql_filter: "entity.roles LIKE '%%ROLE_ADMIN%%'"

easy_admin:
  design:
    menu:
      - { label: 'Users' }
      - { entity: 'Player', label: 'Players', icon: 'users' }
      - { entity: 'Admin', label: 'Admins', icon: 'users' }
```